# Creating a summary list of values based on another cell being blank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that multiple team members use to track open "work" related to requisitions.

I am looking to create a summary page, showing the requisition ID for all "work" that is still in progress. The lookup criteria would be in a range in one column, and the return value would be in another column of the same sheet.

I would then like to take the return values and create a Summary page for all to view. Any suggestions or formulas that will accomplish this?

Example in one tab, Cells in column `B` not containing a date stamp are "open work", The value I would like to return for the "open work" is in column `A` (The value is a 5 digit number). I would like to capture the cells in column `A`, that are "open" in a separate tab for summary purposes

I have created a IF formula = IF(B1="",A1) and got the return I was looking for, my other challenge is How to take info and create a summary tab for multiple worksheets. A summary that would refresh each time a change is made to the lookup value in column B

Comment: Example in one tab, Cells in column B not containing a date stamp are "open work", The value I would like to return for the "open work" is in column A (The value is a 5 digit number). I would like to capture the cells in Column A, that are "open" in a seperate Tab for summary purposes

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53654313/edit) instead of adding information in comments. It would also be useful to know what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you had done this in column C..

> IF formula = IF(B1="",A1)

Then you just need to 'pickup' the values in column C by doing some 'collection' steps..
My way.. I'll put

```
D1 -----> =IF(C1="",0,1)
D2 -----> =IF(C2="",C1,C1+1)
```

and drag the D2 downwards.

Then in 'collect' the column C values in column E. (you may do this in another sheet as per your original need.. I do it in column E for clarity of example.. the logic is the same.. row() will be 'guiding' the listing..)

```
E1 ----> =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D:D,ROW(),0)),"")
```

and drag it downwards.

I think that is what you need. Hope it helps.